# Hibernate Criteria API framework for search functionality?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need to support the  search functionality in my web application.  For example :- there will be 10 fields on one screen on UI.
User can enter the values in those fields and i need to fetch the result from DB. On some screens it can be "And" operation and on  some screens
it can be "OR" operation. So requirements are typically same as in any other web application/product.

I am already using hibernate. So planning to use Criteria API which is perfect for this. I can write framework to handle this search functionality
but i am sure it must have been already done as this kind of requirement is applicable for any product/web application. So i don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Can someone point my is there any third party library or  open source framework already doing this ?

Comment: You don't need to write a framework. You're already using one: Hibernate and its criteria API. The rest is purely specific to your application: which criteria, on which entities, with which operators. And anyway, recommendations for libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I understand that JB Nizet. But as I said search requirement is very generic which any webapp/product must be using. So I am looking for classes(open source API/third party lib) which is catering it in generic fashion and any search requirement will fit to that.  Is there any platform apart from stackoverflow where I can ask for these pointers ?